# Filtering time series to forecast with specific error distribution

Tags: forecasting, python, matlab, arima, signal-processing

I have a time series of weather data (wind). I would like to create a signal from this time series such that the distribution of the difference between the two signals has very specific properties. (Mean of ~0, leptokurtic  (excess kurt of ~1), and an RMSE between 10 and 20%.

So far I'm using a low pass filter, but that does not give me control over the kurtosis. I was thinking of adding random noise, possibly random with a Laplace or Hyperbolic distribution to get the fat tails. But as wind can only have positive values, this is shifting the mean of the forecast signal.

Any ideas how I should best proceed, preferably with methods available in Python or Matlab.

Is it possible to specify these properties with ARIMA models?

Comment: See also [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/), maybe there are relevant threads there.

Comment: great edit to formulate the required errors [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36060/filtering-time-series-to-forecast-with-specific-error-distribution)

Comment: It is probably not recommended to post the same question on two sites at Stack Exchange, perhaps you should delete one of them.

Comment: I'm happy to have this question closed with a link to the other one, I'm not sure how I can close it myself.

Comment: This won't work, I am afraid. You would simply have to delete the question in one of the two sites.